# Running a powershell script via Jenkins on a Linux host

Tags: jenkins, linux, powershell

I have a powershell script cloned into my workspace from a bitbucket repository. If I login to the Jenkins server cli I can run it by doing

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/powershell
pwsh
./psscript.ps1
```

This runs fine as expected, but when I try to run it via Jenkins I get the error

```
/tmp/jenkins2117772455970634975.sh: line 3: ./psscript.ps1: Permission denied
```

My Jenkins user is

```
user.name   netuser
```

and when I do a whoami from both the pwsh cli console and on the linux cli I get the same thing

```
PS /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/powershell> whoami
```

netuser

```
[netuser@server1]$ whoami
netuser
```

Is there another setting I'm missing here?

Comment: Two quick questions? Is it every powershell script or just this one? If it's limited to this script can you share the contents of that script?